# How to fix wi-fi ping hops?

Tags: wireless-networking, ping, wrt54gl

My home network is built using Wi-fi.
I ping my home router

> (192.168.1.1)

from PC and receive nice ping time **< 1ms**. But every 2 minutes ping time gets high **~2000ms** and then goes normal again **< 1ms**. 
When I ping my router from notebook I receive similar behavior however high ping time is about **~100ms**. These ping hops happen every **2 or 3 minutes** but not in the same time on PC and notebook.

Router is Linksys WRT54GL with standard Linksys firmware 4.30.12.3, PC Wi-fi adapter is Linksys WUSB54GC 1.0 with Ralink drivers(default drivers have the same issue), Notebook(Asus U30JC) Wi-fi card is Atheros AR9285.
PC - Windows XP
Notebook - Windows 7

The problem is very similar to this one.
[wi-fi connection drops periodically for a few seconds](https://superuser.com/questions/258416/wi-fi-connection-drops-periodically-for-a-few-seconds)
I have tried to use WEP or no security but ping hops still remain.

How can I fix these ping hops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use Ralink Wireless Utility instead of default Windows Configuration (Zero Configuration). 
I have followed the steps described [here](http://sites.google.com/site/linksysupdateddrivers/linksys-driver-update-how-to) and installed the application.
Ping hops are still present but the highest ping time is ~15ms what is unnoticeable.

I have tried Linksys firmware v. 4.30.13.016 and dd-wrt firmware for my router but it didn't help.